# Equivalent of Pandas Factorize For Multiple Columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have three binary-type columns of a dataframe whose values together constitute a meaningful grouping of the data. To refer to the group, I'm currently making a new column a hard-coded binary encoding like so:

```
data['type'] = data['a'] + 2 * data['b'] + 4 * data['c']
```

Pandas `factorize` will assign an integer for each distinct value of a sequence, but it doesn't seem to work with combinations of multiple columns. Is there a more general pandas function for situations like this? It would be nice if such a function generalized to K distinct categorical variables of arbitrary number of categories, rather than being limited to binary variables.

If such a thing doesn't exist, would there be interest in a pull request?

Comment: I don't know of such a thing.  Assuming I'm right, are you interested in a work around?  Or just if people are interested in asking for a feature?

Comment: I'm just starting a conversation, I'm interesting in any number of relevant responses.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two methods you can try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 0], 
                   'b': [0, 1, 0], 
                   'c': [1, 1, 1]})

>>> df
   a  b  c
0  1  0  1
1  1  1  1
2  0  0  1

>>> ["".join(row) for row in df[['a', 'b', 'c']].values.astype(str)]
Out[22]: ['101', '111', '001']

>>> [bytearray("".join(row)) for row in df[['a', 'b', 'c']].values.astype(str)]
Out[23]: [bytearray(b'101'), bytearray(b'111'), bytearray(b'001')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at `patsy` which addresses things like categorical variable encoding and other model-related issues: [see docs](http://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/categorical-coding.html).

`Patsy` offers quite a few [encoding schemes](http://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/API-reference.html#handling-categorical-data), including:

- Treatment (default)
- Backward difference coding
- Orthogonal polynomial contrast coding
- Deviation coding (also known as sum-to-zero coding), and
- Helmert contrasts